# Java LWJGL Textures Don't draw on mesh

Tags: java, opengl, textures

I'm having pretty common problem by trying to texture simple Triangle with image. Here is the code:

Setup openGL:

```
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();
gluPerspective(70,(float)width/(float)height, 0.3f, view);  
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
glCullFace(GL_FRONT);
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
glEnable(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
```

Mesh Class:

```
 public class Mesh {
        protected int TextureID=0;
        protected int VertID=-1,TrisID=-1,TexID=-1;
        protected Vector3 position,rotation,scale;
    protected ArrayList<Vector3> verts;
    protected ArrayList<Vector3> tris;
    protected ArrayList<Vector3> uvs;
    public Mesh(Vector3 position,Vector3 rotation,Vector3 scale){
        verts= new ArrayList<Vector3>();
        tris= new ArrayList<Vector3>();
        uvs= new ArrayList<Vector3>();
        this.position = position;
        this.rotation=rotation;
        this.scale=scale;
    }
    public void draw(){
        glPushMatrix();{
            // Translate Submatrix
            glScalef(scale.X, scale.Y, scale.Z);
            glRotatef(rotation.X,1,0,0);
            glRotatef(rotation.Y,0,1,0);
            glRotatef(rotation.Z,0,0,1);
            glTranslatef(position.X, position.Y, position.Z);
            //bind and pointer buffers and textures

            TextureLoader.textureList.get(TextureID).bind();
              glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,TextureID);
              GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, TexID);
              glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0);

            glDisableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
              GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VertID);
              glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0);
              int mode = GL_TRIANGLES;

              GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, TrisID);

              //draw
              glDrawElements(mode,tris.size()*3, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);


        }glPopMatrix();
    }

    public Mesh generate(){
    updateVertBuffer();
    updateTrisBuffer();
    updateUvBuffer();
        return this;
    }
    public void updateVertBuffer(){
        if(VertID==-1)VertID= GL15.glGenBuffers();
        FloatBuffer buffer = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(verts.size()*3);
        for(int i=0;i<verts.size();i++){
            buffer.put(verts.get(i).X);
            buffer.put(verts.get(i).Y);
            buffer.put(verts.get(i).Z);
        }
        buffer.flip();
        GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,VertID);
        GL15.glBufferData(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer, GL15.GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    }
    public void updateTrisBuffer(){
        if(TrisID==-1)TrisID = GL15.glGenBuffers();
        IntBuffer buffer = BufferUtils.createIntBuffer(tris.size()*3);
        for(int i=0;i<tris.size();i++){
            buffer.put((int)tris.get(i).X);
            buffer.put((int)tris.get(i).Y);
            buffer.put((int)tris.get(i).Z);
        }
        buffer.flip();
        GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, TrisID);
        GL15.glBufferData(GL15.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer,GL15.GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    }
    public void updateUvBuffer(){
        if(TexID==-1)TexID= GL15.glGenBuffers();
        FloatBuffer buffer = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(uvs.size()*2);
        for(int i=0;i<uvs.size();i++){
            buffer.put(uvs.get(i).Y);
            buffer.put(uvs.get(i).Z);
        }
        buffer.flip();
        GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, TexID);
        GL15.glBufferData(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer, GL15.GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    }
```

Drawing Meshes:

```
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glRotatef(rot.X,1,0,0);
    glRotatef(rot.Y,0,1,0);
    glRotatef(rot.Z,0,0,1);
    glTranslatef(pos.X,pos.Y,pos.Z);
    glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
for(Mesh a : MHandler)a.draw(); // Simply drawing all meshes
glDisableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
    glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    Display.update();
```

Sample Mesh that works, but without textures on it:

```
    Mesh m = new Mesh(new Vector3(0,0,0),new Vector3(0,0,0),new Vector3(10,10,10));
    m.addVert(new Vector3(0,0,0),new Vector3(0,0,0));
    m.addVert(new Vector3(0,1,0),new Vector3(0,1,0));
    m.addVert(new Vector3(0,1,1),new Vector3(0,1,1));
    m.addTriangle(new Vector3(0,1,2));
MHandler.add(m);
```

I know there's a bit too much code, but I don't really know where is excactly the problem. Since I'm new with openGL, any critics about the code would be helpful.
I load Textures using Slick if thats helpful.

Comment: Did you check for errors which are returned by the OpenGL methods? Can you add more information on what you get, e.g. are the meshes rendered but without textures, aren't they rendered at all, etc. (and if it's hard to describe, consider posting an image) ?

Comment: Meshes render but without texture. I can't upload images bcs i need 10 rep

Comment: Do you call `glDisableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);` while rendering a mesh on purpose?

Comment: yeah misstaked. However still doesn't work